# Searchkick (Elasticsearch) histogram with aggregations - extending bounds

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, searchkick

I'm using the searchkick gem in a Rails app to access Elasticsearch data. I use the aggregations feature to display a histogram on price; the relevant part of the body_options looks like this:

```
            price: {
                histogram: {
                    field: :low_rate,
                    interval: 50
                }
            }
```

The issue I'm having is that I also need to be able to provide a filter on low_rate. So, for example, if I initially have a histogram that has a range of rates between $50 and $500, and I add to the next query `where low_rate < 300`, the histogram buckets are recalculated and the chart is entirely redrawn. But in my app I need the chart to still show the same buckets.

This is a pretty common behavior on filters -- see the example below from Airbnb's site, which shows the chart after the upper limit being dragged down -- and so I'm hoping someone might be able to provide some advice about how to achieve this using searchkick.

[image: Example histogram behavior]

Answer (score 0):

I can help you with E.S Query if it helps.

```
{
  "size": 0, 
  "aggs": {
    "hist": {
      "histogram": {
        "field": "low_rate",
        "interval": 50,
        "extended_bounds": { // <======= It is used to extend bounds
          "min": 50,      // <========== Specify the min bound
          "max": 500      // <========== Specify the max bound
        },
          "missing":10    // <========== value of the missing docs in the range
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It gets me part of the way, in that the buckets now extend across the entire range of possible values. However, the buckets outside the selected range show as empty, and I still need the counts in them to show the histogram. For example, if the user drags the minimum slider to 100, and the query has low_rate > 100, all subsequent buckets (start_price 100, 150, 200, etc.) show a count of 0.

Comment: Do you want the query result to be between the range selected and histogram with the extended buckets? On airbnb , price histogram has 2 aspects, (1) Population of histogram and (2) Selecting the range with-in the histogram to create a query for actual data
Please do upvote the answer if it helped you in any ways.

Comment: Yes, I want the query result to be between the range selected. But I want the histogram to continue to show the buckets and their counts, without regard to the query on low_rate. Does that make sense? Perhaps it's not even possible in Elasticsearch? Thanks again.

Comment: @alpheus: You can  load the histogram once and then based on the user's selection of range query can be executed. I see that is doable. In other words Decouple histogram population and query execution part.